# ERROR 'bad operand types for binary operator "-"'

Tags: java

```
 import java.util.Scanner; public class ProgramaCalcularEdad {
    public Float age;
    public String name;
    public String year;
    public String current;
    Scanner datos=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner tem=new Scanner (System.in);

    private void EntradaEdad(){
       System.out.println("Ingrese su Nombre Completo");
       name=tem.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Ingrese su Año de Nacimiento");
       year=datos.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Ingrese el Año Actual");
       current=datos.nextLine();
    }
    
    private void CalculoEdad(){
      age=current-year; //<----- AQUI MARCA EL ERROR
    }

    private void ImpresionEdad(){
       System.out.println("Estimado/a: "+name+" su Edad Actualmente es de: "+age);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner datos=new Scanner(System.in);
       ProgramaCalcularEdad metod=new ProgramaCalcularEdad();
       metod.EntradaEdad();
       metod.CalculoEdad();
       metod.ImpresionEdad();
    }
 }
```

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que he visto muchos tutoriales y no hallo la forma de corregirlo :(
Tengo que entregarlo para el domingo por favor :(
El error que me aparece es el siguiente: `bad operand types for binary operator “-”`
Ya he utilizado `Interger.parseInt` pero aun así tampoco puedo lograr hacer que el código compile, por favor ayúdenme :(

Comment: `java != javascript`

Comment: No puedes restar dos string. Le has hecho  el ParseInt tanto a  current como a year?

Answer (score 0):

De este ejercicio puedes aprender muchas buenas practicas aquí te las enumero (la solución estará al final):

1. Siempre después de ocupar un Scanner o cualquier conexión en tus programas hay
   que cerrarlas, te lo pongo así, en tu casa cierras las puertas después de usarlas
   lo mismo con las conexiones externas en los software Scanner tiene el método
   `close();` para otros métodos de stream tendran los suyos, recomendable poner
   estas conexiones en bloques `try catch finally` donde el `.close();` lo dejamos en
   `finally`
2. Los campos de clase como los que tienes declarados siempre deberian ser private
   y no public y manejar su visibilidad por medios de getters y setters
3. No necesitas dos `scanners` con uno basta.
4. Analiza bien los tipos de datos que necesitas, en este caso tienes `float` para el
   año siendo que los inputs no lo son ya que recibes `String`, pero necesitas
   parsear los a `Integer` o `int` para luego hacer operaciones, estas operaciones
   siempre deben ser del mismo tipo de datos, o sea no restes peras con manzanas

Hay muchas otras buenas practicas por mejorar, pero con eso ya podrías resolver por ti mismo el problema.
Luego de aplicar las buenas practicas y aclaraciones de arriba (punto 4) el codigo del metodo que necesitas quedaria asi

```
    private void EntradaEdad(){
           System.out.println("Ingrese su Nombre Completo");
           name = scanner.nextLine();
           System.out.println("Ingrese su Año de Nacimiento");
           //yearS tipo String
           yearS = scanner.nextLine();
           //year tipo int
           year = Integer.parseInt(yearS);
           System.out.println("Ingrese el Año Actual");
           //currentS tipo String
           currentS = scanner.nextLine();
           //current tipo int
           current = Integer.parseInt(currentS);
           scanner.close();
   }
```

he añadido mas buenas practicas y refactorizado un poco este codigo te comporto este compilador online: https://paiza.io/projects/FnV7YwvvffizYCzW6kIufg